# How to place 90X90 icon

Tags: c#, c++, windows-mobile, winapi, compact-framework

i am creating .cab file installer for windows mobile application,
problem is i need to keep the 90X90 .png image as icon for application.

as per the [link](http://windowsteamblog.com/blogs/windowsphone/archive/2009/08/11/using-custom-icons-in-windows-mobile-6-5.aspx)

i tried to load the icon,step am following are

1) writing the icon path to registry

2) then loading the icon...

i followed the step mentioned above link,

but the problem is i need to restart my device or emulator to get the 90X90 png icon..
i dont no what is the reason... every time i need to restart..
please let me know, how to fix this  probme.. and let me know the reson why its appearing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows Mobile shell caches the icon.  On your first install on a clean device, your icon will be used.  After that, the icon will remain in the cache until the device is reset, so if you want to *change* an icon with an already-installed app, you have to soft reset to force the shell to reload the cache.

Again, this is only a problem when changing the icon for an already-installed app.  It's not going to affect your users when they are installing it on a clean device (and therefore probably is not an issue for you at all).

Comment: it worked for me, as i choose the dynamic method present in the link which i hv mentioned in the above post..